# do I need to use capture list to avoid retain cycle in following code? As if A is not directly holding B and B is holding back to A

Tags: ios, swift, closures, nsoperationqueue, retain-cycle

### Please have a look. I am not sure that following code is having a retain cycle.

I looked other post and article related to retain cycle but still not clear with following code. I intentionally rename classes and other stuff.

```
import UIKit

class SomeInterface {
    var queue: OperationQueue?
    private static var sharedInterface: SomeInterface  = SomeInterface()

    class func getInterface() -> SomeInterface {
        return sharedInterface
    }

    init() {
        queue = OperationQueue()
    }
    class func add(toQueue block : @escaping ()->Void) {
        SomeInterface.getInterface().queue?.addOperation(block)
    }
    func someWork() {
        print("some work")
    }
    deinit {
        print("deinitlized")
    }
}

// Here instance of SomeInterface holding strong reference to **queue**, And //**queue** retains the closure and closure eventually capture "**self**" 
class InterfaceCore {
    class func executeSomeWork() {
        SomeInterface.add(toQueue: { // Should I use capture list here?
            SomeInterface.getInterface().someWork()
        })
    }
}

InterfaceCore.executeSomeWork() // Would it create retain cycle?
```

---

// if yes , am I doing correct in by using capture list.

```
class InterfaceCore {
    class func executeSomeWork() {
        SomeInterface.add(toQueue: { [weak weakInterface = SomeInterface.getInterface() ] in
            if let _ = weakInterface {
                SomeInterface.getInterface().someWork()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no retain cycle here. You can confirm this by calling `isKnownUniquelyReferenced` on your `sharedInterface` to see that it's holding the only reference to the shared instance.

The closure in particular doesn't capture the interface, because it's getting it via `getInterface`, instead of storing a reference to it in the first place.